# Pixel value for rounded corners in Fireworks?

Tags: adobe-fireworks

Im using Fireworks CS5. I need to make a rectangle with rounded corners. There is a tool for this but I cant set the radius in pixels, which I need to do.

I think there is a way of doing this to a normal rectangle with the path tool, but I want this radius to be changeable to another exact value in the future. Thanks

UPDATE This video shows how to do it with the path tool. You can set a pixel value, but then I dont think you can edit this after except by manually adjusting the points by eye.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=exLJHk54Uyk

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I find it easier to use the regular vector rectangle tool (<kbd>U</kbd>) than the special rounded rectangles, for exactly this reason. With a regular rectangle, you can use two methods to round it:

- Set the "Roundness" in pixels or percentage in the Properties panel.

[image: Properties panel in FW]

- Or ungroup the rectangle into a path (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>) and the use the Fillet Points command under the Path panel.

[image: Path panel in FW]

The Fillet method is probably more convenient if you're already working with paths (maybe you're making a complex path where you need to punch a rounded rectangle out of another shape), otherwise the first method is probably a bit faster. You can reverse the effects of Fillet with Sharpen Points, which is the button right next to it in the panel.

Answer (score 0):

the rounded corners tool works fine. You can change the size by clicking one of the yellow markers with "command shift" keys pressed.